# Selenium iframe within iframe

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, src

I have the following python code :

```
 iframe = driver.find_element_by_name("iframe_name")

 driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

 elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/iframe")
```

It is able to find the first iframe element and then switch to it however once it is in it and I try to access the second iframe element (by xpath since it does not have a name or id) I keep getting a "no such element error".

Can someone please help. I am trying to access the interior iframe so that I can get the src attribute within it.

Comment: Can you share your html code... When you are searching for the second iframe try to use the first iframe as the search context instead of driver. But remember to use a dot at the beginning if u use xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions.

1. Try using wait for an element by XPath ("/html/body/iframe"), as often times the driver will fail to wait till switching to the frame is completed.
2. Make sure that your XPath ("/html/body/iframe") is working. Also try identifying element using the tag name if there only one IFrame in the IFrame.

Hope that helps.